# What is the default drawable for pressing a list item

Tags: android, state, selector

When the user presses a ListView item (android:state_pressed="true") it flashes a shade of yellow (or you can press and hold).

What drawable is this?  I've created my own selector because I want my own ListView item color , but I lose the pressed color.

There's an Android doc about skinning buttons that references #ffff0000, but this produces red.

Does anyone know what it is and how to reference it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The default system resources can be found in `<android-sdk>/platforms/android-<version>/data/res`. In particular, the list selector is defined in `drawable/list_selector_background.xml`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_window_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@color/transparent" />

    <!-- Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states so the drawable will invalidate itself when coming out of pressed state. -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_disabled" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_disabled" />

    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_focus" />

</selector>
```

The drawable that is shown on a press, `list_selector_background_transition`, is not a single color but two 9-patch images, a yellow and a white one, with an animated transition between them.

```
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/list_selector_background_pressed"  />
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/list_selector_background_longpress"  />
</transition>
```

Comment: In short: You want to reference @android:drawable/list_selector_background_transition

Comment: When I build my own selector, why can't I reference @android:drawable/list_selector_background_transition?

Comment: I noticed that as well. In short, I don't know why. However, you can create your own copy of list_selector_background_transition in your project. You can then reference that one.

Comment: @Jonas it's because they're not publicly visible.

Comment: I think that for new Android versions, this selector (list_selector_background) isn't used, since they are still yellow, while the new ones are blue (or gray, starting from Kitkat). Question is, how do you get the new ones?

Answer (score 2):

The thing your talking about is the Android OS built-in selector.

Make your own highlight with an xml-file in your drawable-folder like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#YOURCOLOR" /> 
  <item android:color="#FE896F" /> 
</selector>
```

Then in your XML-file there you have your ListView.

```
android:textColor="@drawable/highlight" //For text to appear like YOURCOLOR
//or if you wish the background
android:background="@drawable/highlight" //For the background to appear like YOURCOLOR
```

I hope this is it and tell me if this worked or not!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've already created a selector file like this.  I used Romain Guy's trick to maintain a scroll pad selector on list items I've set a background color for.  What I'm looking for is Android's default state_pressed color.

Comment: You can do an ugly hack like print the pressed item and then look up the RGB color, but of course, the default color is declared somewhere.
The problem is how to find it

Comment: It actually looks more like a gradient of some value

Comment: I believe it to be list_selector_background_pressed, but I don't know how to reference it.  I've tried @android:drawable/list_selector_background_pressed, but to no avail

Comment: It's like a mystery; I would be very appreciated for me to know the solution for this. Otherwise; it can't be like it is unavailable for programmers to change this specific thing?

Answer (score 1):

A color is defined as #AARRGGBB  where AA represents the alpha (transparency) value, RR the amount of red, GG the amount of green, and BB the amount of blue.  Thus #ffff0000 is solid and all red.  If you want orange, you want to add some green, i.e: #ffffA500.  Google for RGB color values to see pages of colors with their rgb values.

Comment: Yea, I've got this.  I was just wondering the Android default.  But thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

I have used a color picker tool in a photo editing application to find the outer and inner colors of the gradient and made my own.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#ffb300"
        android:centerColor="#ffc800"
        android:endColor="#ffb300"
        android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```