# android - adding a custom view to listview makes the selector color disappear

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have written code for a custom ListView. It is just a view with three textfields. I have used setBackgroundColor to set the row background to white. However, when I click on a row, the color no longer changes. I am doing this entirely programmatically. Is there a method to get back the Android selector color on clicking a ListView row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changing selection colour is a property of the background drawable belonging to the list item. You will have to specify one yourself, using a state list drawable.

More info here:

[Drawable Resources: State List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

And here:

[What is the default drawable for pressing a list item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506976/what-is-the-default-drawable-for-pressing-a-list-item)

Annoyingly, the system's default list item background is not accessible from apps, so you'll have to copy the original (or use your own style if you prefer).